# FuelPHP ORM do not return any data

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

I start using Fuelphp v1.7.3 but if I want to get all data from my mysql table nothing happens. I have ORM autoloaded, my model has defined table name, primary key and also (as properties) all my columns from that table. But if i put to my controller

```
$data['pagedata'] = Model_Admin_Cms::find('all');
```

and

`$this->template->content = View::forge('path/to/browse', $data);`

and in view browse.php i have `print_r($pagedata)` it do nothing (nor in the debug bar there is 0 SQL queries).

Many thanks.

Comment: 0 queries is very suspicious. Can you make sure `Model_Admin_Cms::find('all')` runs?

Comment: Also, don't use `print_r` for debugging (or for anything else), because it outputs nothing if your value is an empty string, or `null`, so you can't differentiate between them.

Comment: Many thanks Barta. I change for experimental purposes print_r  to var_dump and it works now, i got my query results. But from debug bar is still 0 querries, so it doesn't matter.Thank you once again.

Comment: I see. You're welcome. Though it's strange that number of queries shows 0.

Comment: The query count will only show up if profiling is enabled on the DB connection. http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/profiling.html#/database_profiling